# To view percentage change for time periods in NRQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, newrelic, nrql

can we use two since and until clause in NRQL using subquery?

i need to obtain the change percentage of present week data with the previous week data in NRQL

i am not able to get the right query.

[i want to get the change percentage only to be displayed. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4KVc.png)]

I tired using this formula

```
Percentage Change = ((( Present Value − Past Value Past Value )) / Past value ) x 100
```

but i am not able to get the right NRQL.

I got suggestions to try UNION and Subqueries,yet to try them.